# How to catch Maximize started event using Window Message, etc

Tags: .net, wpf, winapi, maximize

I was able to get Maximized and Size changed events, but not Maximize started.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-windowposchanging

Comment: Actually I tried WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING earlier but it was sent to all events like Z index changed, window moved, resized. So I just added a bit of logic to check if size is equals to working area size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my problem.
Here is hook method that you can add for your code and do all needed staff before Window Maximized event occurs.

```
    private static void WmWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        WINDOWPOS wpos = (WINDOWPOS)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(WINDOWPOS));
        IntPtr monitorContainingApplication = MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);

        if (monitorContainingApplication == IntPtr.Zero)
            return;

        var monitorInfo = new MONITORINFO();
        GetMonitorInfo(monitorContainingApplication, monitorInfo);
        var rcWorkArea = monitorInfo.rcWork;

        if (wpos.x == rcWorkArea.left &&
            wpos.y == rcWorkArea.top &&
            wpos.cx == rcWorkArea.right &&
            wpos.cy == rcWorkArea.bottom)
        {
            // Do required staff before windows maximized state has changed
        }
    }
```

Add this method to WindowProc like this

```
    private static IntPtr WindowProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        switch (msg)
        {
            case 0x0046: //  WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING
                WmWindowPos(hwnd, lParam);
                break;
        }

        return (IntPtr)0;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, you can mark your own answer to end this thread. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread in the future.